# React-calendar Ui not switching when value is set from function after single interaction

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-calendar

The UI of the react calendar is not switching to the respective month when the value is set functionally after the calendar has been touched (dirty).

```
export default function App() {
  const [date, setDate] = useState([
    new Date('2022-05-10'),
    new Date('2022-05-15'),
  ]);
  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setDate([new Date('2022-11-02'), new Date('2022-11-08')])}>click</button>
          <Calendar
            value={date}
            onChange={(v) => {
              setDate(v);
            }}
            selectRange
            minDate={new Date()}
            defaultStartDate={date[0]}
          />
        </div>
      </p>
)
}
```

If the button is clicked post a manual selection of dates has been made. (calendar component clicked and selection made). Then the date value changes but the UI stays intact.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `activeStartDate` prop manually also to have a fully controlled calendar.

This is the code that worked for me (I receive the controlled date from props):

```
export default function Calendar({ date, handleDateChange }) {
  return <MiniCalendar
           value={date.toDate()}
           activeStartDate={date.startOf('month').toDate()}
           onChange={handleDateChange}
           showNavigation={false} />
}
```

I use `dayjs` dates to handle my state and retrieve the first day of the month.

Useful link: https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar/issues/358.